# javascript included twice in a Rails 3.1 asset-based app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Although the title of the question is very similar to a number of previous ones, my issue seems different.

Briefly, *the first item* in the js manifest is included twice.

Here's the whole of my `/app/assets/javascript/application.js` file in a Rails 3.1 application:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require utilities
```

And here's a snippet of the rendered page's source:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/autocomplete-rails.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/utilities.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please note that if I move up to the top any of the other lines in `application.js` like so:

```
//= require utilities
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

It is always the first item that gets included twice!

```
<script src="/assets/utilities.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/utilities.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/autocomplete-rails.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*UPDATE*

As a temporary workaround, I added `//= require dummy` at the top of the list, which points to an empty dummy.js file. Although it appears twice in the rendered page, it has no effect, as it does nothing. On the other hand, if I set `config.assets.debug = false` in `development.rb`, as often suggested, then ALL of my javascript gets loaded twice:

```
<script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and js actions are fired twice (e.g. confirm dialogs pop up twice when deleting a model)

Giuseppe

Comment: do you have files in public/assets by any chance? if you do delete them as this could be causing this duplication

Comment: No, there's no assets directory in my development's /public

Comment: Have you tried changing config/environments/development.rb config.assets.debug to false, wondering if it does the 'the right thing' when it concats all of the assets

Comment: I did try, and it wreaked havoc. Please see the update to the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the culprit was the [rails-widgets](https://github.com/paolodona/rails-widgets) plugin, and in particular [this bit of code](https://github.com/paolodona/rails-widgets/blob/master/lib/widgets/core.rb), part of the widgets' initialization.

After removing it, all went back to normal. Javascript assets are now loaded once as expected, in both development and production.

While I apologize for not finding out sooner that the problem was quite specific to my setup, I still hope that the solution may serve some purpose. Thank you all.

Giuseppe

Answer (score 13):

I had faced something similar before and I just left a the first link blank and it worked for me. Give it a try.

```
/*leave the following line empty */

//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require utilities
```

Comment: unfortunately no, i tried to dig the dependencies and what is called where but it doesn't make a lot of sense. The thing is it works

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

[Rails 3.1 Assets - Strange Serving in Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356251/rails-3-1-assets-strange-serving-in-development)

You should also check to see that you haven't compiled your assets i.e there is no public/assets directory. If there is delete it, bounce your server and you should be good to go.

Ultimately, both of these solutions didn't work for me so I just set config.assets.debug to false. I can't really debug my js that way, but at least it fixes the problem for now.

Comment: config.assets.debug = false makes things worse. Please see the update to the original question. Thanks!

Comment: And you tried Vosobe Kapsimanis answer by having a comment and then an empty line above everything? Have you tried comparing your config to a fresh rails app? Though, it really sounds a lot like the empty line issue to me, which seems like a bug on rails' part.