# jQuery lib include conflict with rails3 and twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I've an app with rails3 using jQuery by default and twitter-bootstrap-rails and got a problem.

jQuery seems to be included twice, causing links using `:remote => true` to be called twice too..

If i put the return of `javscript_include_tag :application` in my app directly and do some tests i got the following:

- jquery.js with no application.js => remote links works perfectly
- jquery.js with application.js => remote links called twice
- no jquery.js but application.js at the top => remote links called twice too

My application.js just contain:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Any ideas how to resolve this problem cleanly ?

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356251/rails-3-1-assets-strange-serving-in-development) that solves the issue. Its a bug with the asset pipeline and was filed [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5145).