# Why is my dropdown menu with Bootstrap not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my Rails application, I have the following code for a dropdown menu:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
    <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li> 
            <% if signed_in? %>
                <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data toggle="dropdown">
                        Account <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
```

In my application.js file I have the following code:

```
    //= require bootstrap
```

I have no idea why the dropdown menu isn't working, and I have no idea how to fix it. A few days ago, it was working fine, and now it no longer functions properly. Thanks for any help!

Comment: did you download the dropdown javascript file from twitter bootstrap?

Comment: I see `data toggle` in your code, should it be `data-toggle`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [twitter bootstrap drop down suddenly not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218587/twitter-bootstrap-drop-down-suddenly-not-working)

Comment: Is the 'turbolinks' enabled? Make sure: document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  // ...
})

Answer (score 11):

I figured out the answer from this previous StackOverflow question:

[twitter bootstrap drop down suddenly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218587/twitter-bootstrap-drop-down-suddenly-not-working)

I had to put //= require jquery below my line of code that required bootstrap, and then it worked!

Comment: and then I had to move it back up, and it also worked :/ but other elements didn't

Comment: yay!  I spend 2 hours trying to figure this out!  THANKS!

Comment: @user1483441 It works but as Aleks said, other jquery elements are not working because bootstrap loads fist and uses jquery but jquery in not loaded at that time

Answer (score 8):

I tested your HTML code and it worked fine.

First of all, make sure you are loading jQuery first:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
```

Also, you have to call the dropdown via javascript:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Where should I call dropdown with the javascript you gave me? I added the javascript to my header file and it still isn't working.

Comment: You can add it to the end of application.js - if you add it to the header then it gets loaded before your assets, which will not work.

Comment: Fixed for me. Was following a tutorial and they forgot this line :)

Answer (score 5):

The solution lies in the order you import the javascript dependencies.

This is what I had initially in my `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

When I removed `bootstrap-sprockets` i my dropdown worked. However, I did not want to remove `bootstrap-sprockets`. So My new order looked like this;

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Then, to be safe, I had to clean and pre-compile assets by running the following;

```
rake assets:clean
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I've got in the same problem with default Rails and [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) gem installation.

Direct call of dropdown initialisation works indeed, but it looks like kind of a workaround for me. So, I continued to search for the answers and was able to find the one that looks more appropriate:

> I have solved this issue.
>   I add following code in users.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

Solution was found [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/5303122#1153710). Thus, I added this code to *app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js.coffee*, so the final code in it looks like the following:

```
jQuery ->
  $("a[rel~=popover], .has-popover").popover()
  $("a[rel~=tooltip], .has-tooltip").tooltip()
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

And right after this dropdown in navbar started to work exactly as expected.

Comment: I had an issue where the dropdown would work perfectly find upon a page refresh, but as soon as I navigated to a different page it would cease working. I added that one line (`$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`) to the `bootstrap.js.coffee` file and things worked like a charm. Thanks!

Edit: Now looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24457190/1814019) it looks like my issue may be TurboLinks related. Either way, this still worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue for the whole day but was finally able to fix it. 
I applied the solution above (changing the order) and the dropdown worked. However, I noticed in the console there were errors (Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined) due to the fact that bootstrap-sprockets was called before jQuery. 
I have found a solution that worked for me [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/714)

Basically, I have included the following code below the required items in application.js as:

```
   //= require jquery
   //= require tether
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require bootstrap
   //= require bootstrap-sprockets
   //= require turbolinks
   //= require_tree .


   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
   });
```

For me this worked like a charm. Hope that helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and removing `//= require bootstrap` from my `application.js` worked for me. I hope this too helps someone!