# rails + jquery - errors on every page but it still works (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am working on a rails app. It is a standard app, using server rendered pages, and jquery. I have had a decently hard time wrangling together the jquery and i am not sure why.

I am using jquery for a couple things: a [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and a [timepicker](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/). That is only used for a form a user can use, and is rendered in a users section where they can create/edit.

The structure of my javascript is right now i am using 1 javascript file called `main` which is required in my `application.js`. That is all the JS i am using.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap.min.js
//= require jquery.raty.min.js
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require main
//= require_tree .
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // users profile stuff
    if ($('table.calendar tbody tr td ul').hasClass('active-trip')) {
    $('.active-trip').parent().css('background-color', 'orange');
  }

  $("#trip_start_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 1
  });

  $("#start_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 1
  });
  $("#end_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 1
  });
  // ==========


  // js in user's trips
  $('#trip_start_time').timepicker();

  $('#trip_end_time').timepicker();
  // ===========

});
```

The problem that I am having is I am using a bootstrap navbar, with some JS effects on it (dropdowns). On this one page (a resource called "Gyms", or /gyms) the JS completely breaks and leaves the navbar useless. The error that I am getting is

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).timepicker is not a function`

And I notice when I get that error once, it then starts repeating and I get it on every page. But yet, when I go back to the form where i use this code, it works completely fine *even with the error*?

This might be a turbolinks issue, but I am really not sure. I am using these gems

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

if that helps anything. I have also played around with using the jQuery CDN script rendered in `application.html.erb` but that doesn't really seem to help or hurt anything and is pretty much neutral. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the order of requiring:

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery.turbolinks
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //
 // ... your other scripts here ...
 //
 //= require turbolinks
```

put jquery.tubolinks before all other scripts but right after jquery

Comment: thanks for the answer. putting the `jquery.tubolinks` above everything else got a `$ is not a function` error, then putting `jquery` above the `jquery-turbolinks` fixed that error, but resulted in the original error still

Comment: are you actually including the timepicker js? I can't see that you do in your question

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I can't believe i forgot that! that took away the error, but still a weird "bug" that sometimes i can click on my navbar drop down, but other times i cannot. No error, no nothing. Some pages i can't click on it, some pages i can click on it. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: nvm i think this solved that annoying bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697789/why-is-my-dropdown-menu-with-bootstrap-not-working