# Javascript plugins are not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have cloned one rails(3.2.13) project from git repository. CSS styles are working fine. But whole javascript plugins are not loading.

Eg: Bootstrap's dropdown(nav-list) list is not showing, ajax request is not working etc.

I have checked it by precompiling the assets but still it is not working. I have checked the same project with others, it is working fine for them.
Please help me to solve this issue.

In application.js,

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require twitter/bootstrap
 //= require bootstrap-datepicker
 //= require_tree .
```

In jquery console, i am getting below errors,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Comment: where is twitter/bootstrap located in your project?

Comment: Sorry i don't know exact location because i have used bootstrap's gem & installation command to isntall bootstrap. 
Once we precompiled then it will display in <rails_project_name>/public/assets/twitter/bootstrap

Comment: Hi Shruthi, everything seems to be okay for me,
can you check these, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218587/twitter-bootstrap-drop-down-suddenly-not-working

Comment: I am getting javascript errors also... i have put that errors above.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to development.rb,

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

Here no need to precompile the assets.