# Dropdown menu is not working in server side Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails application my dropdown menu is not working after deploying code on server but in locally its work fine.I cant understand what is the main issue. Even I try this link [twitter bootstrap drop down suddenly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218587/twitter-bootstrap-drop-down-suddenly-not-working). But its not working for me.Code was run good before But suddenly its not working.My application.js is

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require_tree ./bootstrap
 //= require jquery.remotipart
 //= require jquery-1.7.2.min
 //= require jquery.loadmask
 //= require highcharts
 //= require exporting
 //= require highcharts-3d
 //= require jquery.cslider
 //= require modernizr.custom.28468
 //= require owl.carousel
 // require app
```

This is my forth day with this problem I am still in trouble. In my app/asset/javascript/bootstrap directory bootstrap.min file present.

Comment: no one can tell you why its not working since you wrote nothing about it .i.e. code, environment  please add some more detail

Comment: have you try to run it on local in production mode ??

Comment: I run it in development mode

Comment: run your application on local in production mode first and see it is working

Comment: you are using
`//= require jquery`
and then again
`//= require jquery.min`
I think jquery.min should suffice replace  `jquery` with `jquery.min` , remove the other one and see if it works.

Comment: I remove jquery.min. But its not working

Comment: after trying remove jquery.min remove jquery..still not working