# How to access assets during development if precompiling for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, asset-pipeline

I recently deployed a first iteration of a project to Heroku. Because I precompiled, all of my assets used during development are now in the public/assets and public/system folders.

I am [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356251/rails-3-1-assets-strange-serving-in-development) of two options for accessing my assets during development. The default option seems to be to allow the public/assets files to override my app/assets files. However, if I do this, any CSS changes I make in app/assets is not reflected.

The alternative option is to access ONLY the app/assets folder through:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

However, by doing this, I can't see any of my images during development, as they have already been precompiled and moved to public/system

Is there a way to access my CSS/JS files from app/assets, yet still load my images from public/system?

Or am I supposed to do all of my CSS/JS development out of the public/assets folder? Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deploy I like to run

```
rake assets:clean
```

to get rid of the compiled/compressed assets in `public/assets`. This let's Rails look back to my `app/assets` directory in development mode since none of my assets are in `public/assets` anymore.

Also, unless your circumstances are special, you should be putting your images into `app/assets/images`, not `public/system`. `rake assets:precompile` pushes images into `public/assets` too. When doing this, you need to use `image_path(...)` within your `___.css.scss` file(s) to allow the paths to be updated properly with the hashed filename generated for the image assets during precompile.

Finally, it seems reading through **[this Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)** would do you a lot of good.

Comment: Hi @Deefour, thanks for the feedback. That sounds about right. Let me see if I can fix my images path, and I'll give it a try. Do you have a path/url specified in the has_attached_file line of your model?

Comment: `has_attached_file`? I have no idea what you're referring to, sorry.

Comment: Hi @Deefour, thanks again for your help. rake assets:clean worked perfectly afterall. The issue was, I'm using Paperclip, and my uploaded images get saved to public/system during development. However, this is fine, as it doesn't have to be precompiled for production, and it doesn't get removed by rake assets:clean.